# How to show File upload in Flex with progress bar

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, progress-bar

I am writing a sample code in AS3, Flash Builder 4.6 to upload a file to server. Below is the code,

```
var FILE:File = new File("MyPackage.zip");
var URLrequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest(URL);
var variables:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
variables.login = view.LOGIN;
variables.password = view.PASSWORD;
variables.file_name = FILE_NAME;

URLrequest.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
URLrequest.data = variables;

FILE.addEventListener(Event.OPEN, OpenHandler);
FILE.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, UploadProgress);
FILE.addEventListener(DataEvent.UPLOAD_COMPLETE_DATA, OnSuccessfulUpload);
FILE.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, OnUnsuccessfulUpload);

FILE.upload(URLrequest);
```

Here is the UploadProgress function,

```
/**
Function:       UploadProgress
Description:    The function is called at the upload progress of the file.
@param:event    event contains the details of the Progress method.
*/
private function UploadProgress(event:ProgressEvent):void
{
    try
    {
        // view.uploadProgress is the ProgressBar component
        view.uploadProgress.setProgress(event.bytesLoaded, event.bytesTotal);
    }
    catch(e:Error)
    {
        trace(e.message);
    }
}
```

The problem is that sometimes the above code causes my application to crash. I tried debugging but could not find a reason. Subsequently, I fount that if the ProgressEvent listener is not added to the file object, the crash disappears. But so does my progress bar.

I googled but always came across examples that included FileReference object to listen for the Event.Select event for the selection of the file to upload. But I do not need it, as I know which file I have to upload. Is there any other way I can do this?

There was also the option for my own custom progress bar. But, I do not have much guidance for it.

Please help!
Thanks

Comment: what do you mean crash?

Comment: I am developing a Flex extension in Flash Builder 4.6 using Extension Builder 2.1 for InDesign.. By crash I meant that my extension unloads itself... and sometimes InDesign stops working.

Comment: you should wrap upload() within a try/catch.

Comment: Didn't work.. I modified the above code to look like this,  try{FILE.upload(URLrequest);}catch(e:Error){trace(e.message);}

Comment: Post your UploadProgress function.  It sounds like the crash happens there; we might be able to help.

Comment: I have edited my question to include the UploadProgress function.